# Hardware requirements for using sentence-transformers/all-MiniLM-L6-v2

Tags: huggingface-transformers, sentence-similarity, sentence-transformers

Can someone please advise me upon the hardware requirements of using **sentence-transformers/all-MiniLM-L6-v2** for a semantic similarity use-case. I had downloaded the model locally and am using it to generate embedding, and finally using **util.pytorch_cos_sim** to calculate similarity scores between 2 sentences. All was working good in my Mac Pro ( *2.4 GHz 8-Core Intel Core i9 processor and 32 GB memory*); but after I moved the model to containers of *1 core CPU and 4 GB RAM* (within my company provided network), the code is taking at least 15-20 times more time to generate the cosine similarity score.

Did someone face a similar situation? Kindly advise.
Thank you in advance for the help!

N.B.: I am also sharing the sample code for reference.

```
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer, util
sentences = ["What happens when my account is debited", "What is a debit"]

# Model Instantiation
sent_sim_model = SentenceTransformer('./all-MiniLM-L6-v2')
embedding_0= sent_sim_model.encode(sentences[0], convert_to_tensor=True)
embedding_1 = sent_sim_model.encode(sentences[1], convert_to_tensor=True)

# Calculate cosine sim score:
print(util.pytorch_cos_sim(embedding_0, embedding_1).tolist()[0][0])
```

I have been running the model successfully in my local system for quite sometime now (after storing it locally in the same directory as that of the code), but once I had moved the model and the above code to a docker container , the response time (which used to be between 2-3 secs in my local system) had gone up to more than 1 minute. Since each container I am using has got a configuration of 1 CPU core and 4 GB RAM, I would like to get inputs on the fact if this low hardware can be the issue for the above code .

Comment: On your Mac Pro, did you measure the performance of cold runs? I am asking because the time you report is like a 100 times slower than the measurements in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76881266/2725810) post.

Answer (score 0):

I can't add a comment so giving a full reply

I built a tiny docker rest API with Flask and deployed it to https://fly.io/ with under `2gb`, and I get pretty good results

```py
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from flask_cors import CORS
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer, util
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from flask import request

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
load_dotenv()

model = SentenceTransformer('sentence-transformers/all-MiniLM-L6-v2')

@app.route('/get_embeddings', methods=['POST'])
def get_embeddings():
    text = request.json.get('text')
    embeddings = model.encode(text)
    return jsonify(embeddings=embeddings.tolist())


@app.route('/get_score', methods=['GET'])
def get_score():
    #   {
    #     "text": [
    #         "What happens when my account is debited",
    #         "What is a debit"
    #     ]
    # }
    # sentences = request.json.get('text') # [str, str]
    sentences = ["What happens when my account is debited", "What is a debit"]
    embedding_0= model.encode(sentences[0], convert_to_tensor=True)
    embedding_1 = model.encode(sentences[1], convert_to_tensor=True)
    score = util.pytorch_cos_sim(embedding_0, embedding_1).tolist()[0][0]
    return jsonify(score=score)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.run(host="0.0.0.0", debug = False)
```

built with nixpack

```bash
nixpacks build ./ --name embedder
```

run locally

```bash
docker run -m 1gb --cpus 1 -p 5000:5000 embedder
```

```bash
flyctl scale memory 2048 -a embedder
```

deploy to Fly or Railway and test using postman, it takes a few seconds to show the results

Comment: but what are the results you've got?