# HuggingFace Inference Endpoints extremely slow performance

Tags: huggingface-transformers, word-embedding, huggingface

I compute vector embeddings for text paragraphs using the [all-MiniLM-L6-v2 model at HuggingFace](https://huggingface.co/sentence-transformers/all-MiniLM-L6-v2). Since the free endpoint wasn't always responsive enough and I need to be able to scale, I deployed the model to HuggingFace Inference Endpoints. To begin with, I chose the cheapest endpoint.

To my surprise, a single request to compute 35 embeddings took more than 7 seconds (according to the log at HuggingFace). Based on the suggestion of HuggingFace support, I tried to upgrade to 2 CPUs and it got even slower (to tell the truth, I am not sure why they thought that a single request would benefit from another CPU). Next, I tried GPU. The request now takes 2 seconds.

I must be missing something, because it seems impossible that one would pay >$400/month to serve a single request in 2 seconds, rather than serving thousands of request per second.

I guess that I must be missing something, but I don't see what it could be.

I submit the requests using the command in the following format:

```bash
curl https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.us-east-1.aws.endpoints.huggingface.cloud -X POST -d '{"inputs": ["My paragraphs are of about 200 words on average", "Another paragraph", etc.]}' -H 'Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
```

What could I be missing?

P.S. For the GPU, it does get much better once warmed up, achieving 100ms. However, this particular model [achieves 14,200 embeddings per second on A100](https://www.sbert.net/docs/pretrained_models.html#model-overview). Granted it's not A100 that I ran it on, but 350 embeddings per second is still way too slow.

Comment: Well, hello there again. :^) Just out of curiosity, is there a speed difference between free and paid APIs in terms of speed?

Comment: @doneforaiur Actually, the free API can be faster. But it is unpredictable and can sometimes take 20 seconds for the described query.

Answer (score 1):

To test the one CPU core efficiency I used:

```
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
import time

sentences = ["This is an example sentence each sentence is converted"] * 10

model = SentenceTransformer('sentence-transformers/all-MiniLM-L6-v2', device='cpu')

for i in range(100):
    start_time = time.time()
    embeddings = model.encode(sentences)
    end = time.time()
    print("Time taken: ", end - start_time)
```

And ran it with:

```
taskset -c 0 python soquestion.py
```

Which run 10 sentence embeddings in this much seconds:

```
...
Time taken:  0.035448551177978516
Time taken:  0.035162925720214844
Time taken:  0.03574204444885254
Time taken:  0.035799264907836914
Time taken:  0.03513455390930176
Time taken:  0.03690838813781738
Time taken:  0.035082340240478516
Time taken:  0.035216331481933594
Time taken:  0.0348513126373291
...
```

But if I use all of my cores:

```
...
Time taken:  0.016519546508789062
Time taken:  0.01624751091003418
Time taken:  0.017212390899658203
Time taken:  0.016582727432250977
Time taken:  0.019397735595703125
Time taken:  0.016611814498901367
Time taken:  0.017941713333129883
Time taken:  0.01743769645690918
...
```

So I would say core count affects speed. I'm using an AMD Ryzen 5 5000, so might or might not be significantly slower than the `Intel Xeon Ice Lake` CPUs Hugging Face provide (they don't really tell you the model and the performance varies so much...).

However, I can say that your instances are insufficient memory wise because the [doc](https://huggingface.co/docs/inference-endpoints/pricing)s for pricing states:

```
aws     small   $0.06   1   2GB     Intel Xeon - Ice Lake
aws     medium  $0.12   2   4GB     Intel Xeon - Ice Lake
aws     large   $0.24   4   8GB     Intel Xeon - Ice Lake
aws     xlarge  $0.48   8   16GB    Intel Xeon - Ice Lake
azure   small   $0.06   1   2GB     Intel Xeon
azure   medium  $0.12   2   4GB     Intel Xeon
azure   large   $0.24   4   8GB     Intel Xeon
azure   xlarge  $0.48   8   16GB    Intel Xeon
```

And you mentioned using 1 to 2 vCPUs which comes with 2-4 GB of RAM. I investigated how much RAM is used by this process by:

```
/usr/bin/time -v python soquestion.py |& grep resident
        Maximum resident set size (kbytes): 981724
        Average resident set size (kbytes): 0
```

Which is 1 GB. Compared to CPU instances, a lot. Compared to GPU instances, very little. I would suggest you to consider upgrading your instances *altough* I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76618655/hardware-requirements-for-using-sentence-transformers-all-minilm-l6-v2) which is struggling even with 4 GB of RAM.

Comment: I don't understand. First, if all that is required is 1GB, then at least the second instance I was using, `aws medium` with 4GB should have run at least 100 times faster than the time I report in the question. Second, if memory is the issue, upgrading to 2 CPUs with the respective memory increase should have helped significantly, but it didn't.

Comment: I believe only the model used 1 GB, the system as a whole might use much more. But I think it's correct to assume 2 vCPU would be faster than 1 vCPU. The used RAM doesn't change when I play around with core counts either. I'm going to limit the memory and check the results but that might take a while. :^)

Comment: Also, in the other post that you cited, the OP was perfectly satisfied with 2 embeddings in 2 seconds on a 32 GB machine! He got like 200 times worse performance than you did...

Comment: They were saying that "2 seconds for 2 embeddings in Docker container, 20 times slower than on my machine", which would make the local embeddings take 0.1 seconds. Somehow it's still way slower than my machine (mind you, my machine is not that great). Will build some Docker images to test, in the meantime could you test it with a `large` or `xlarge` instance?

Comment: He wrote: "once I had moved the model and the above code to a docker container , the response time (which used to be between 2-3 secs in my local system) had gone up to more than 1 minute. " So, it was 2-3 secs on his local machine without the docker. With the docker, it took more than 1 minute.

Comment: Oh I see, my bad. Damn. The suggested answer is not good too but "normal" for the OP. In my opinion, 2 seconds is not acceptable for this kind of model.

Comment: I think he was measuring cold runs and it took 2 seconds for the whole thing to load into memory. I can't find any other explanation for it running so slow on a local system without a docker.

Comment: Last thing that I can think of is the internet connection. You are making HTTP requests which takes time to establish a connection for each request. This might explain 100 ms on the GPU situation (but you mentioned `according to the log at HuggingFace`, could you include those logs too?).

Comment: I don't think HTTP requests can explain it. When I ran short sentences, i.e. `["I like you"] * 35`, it gets done in 17ms on the GPU. Thus, I think the time it shows in the logs is measured on the backend.

Comment: I have reproduced your results (the same input that you used) on my Precision 5520 laptop (11th Gen I7 with 64 GB RAM) under Ubuntu under WSL2. The first call to `model.encode` took 213ms, but the subsequent 9 calls took 13-19ms. Next, I ran my long paragraphs and they took about 1.2 seconds on average... I was unable to limit memory with `ulimit -v 2000000 && p
ython test.py`. The error I got was: `ImportError: libcusparse.so.11: failed to map segment from shared object`.

Comment: Yup, just going to comment that same thing. It only works with 3GB and up. So `ulimit -v 3000000`. Limiting memory doesn't seem to have an affect on the performance, I still got 0.03 seconds for 10 sentence embeddings.

Comment: Also checked the [Azure VM Performances](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/compute-benchmark-scores), they are not that bad, even the smaller ones.

Comment: So how come it worked with 1GB machine? It should have crushed, not just been slow...

Comment: That's my question too. I wonder if this happens on other embedding models. Hmm...

Comment: Also, if memory is not important, that means their machine with 2 vCPUs and 4GB of RAM is 8 times slower than my laptop (with the virtualization of WSL2!), which is quite a shame.